# Need Clarification on error Android Development with Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, android, visual-studio, cordova, apache-cordova

I am trying to learn more about developing apps on Android by following [this guide](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/vs-taco-2017-first-app/#run).

When I attempt to run the blank Cordova project I get an error, regardless if I turn deploy ON or OFF.

With deploy **OFF** I get the error(s):

> Unable to get launched browser process for your app.

With deploy **ON** I get the error(s):

```
assert.js:90

AssertionError: missing path

at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)

at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

at Module.load (module.js:343:32)

at Module.require (module.js:351:3)

at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)

at node.js:968:3

at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\f6dfaae9\taco-toolset-6.3.1\simulate.js:15:13)
Description

at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)

at require (internal/module.js:12:17)

at startup (node.js:139:18) 

Node process unexpectedly exited while waiting for property 'appUrl'.

throw new assert.AssertionError(
```

As I am fairly new to Android development and Visual Studio, any help would be appreciated.

I have installed Google Chrome.

Comment: i dont have the solution, just wanted to tell you you are not alone with this issue, struggling with it too

Answer (score 0):

Recently I also faced this issue.

As per suggestion from the following thread,

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a894d640-113a-4a47-9686-4d9ef50755c8/need-help-with-error-on-apache-cordova-with-visual-studio-andriod-development-?forum=ToolsForApacheCordova

I reinstalled Cordova tools and problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across the same problem. Through command lines bellow I discovered that the configuration of one plugin was wrong

```
cordova clean android
```

and

```
cordova build android
```

I hope to help someone in the same situation.